# How to know when listener is called

Tags: android, callback, listener

My friend gave me a modified SDK with new interfaces and classes and i have to create a notification application.
The purpose is to create a notification when  the listener is called.

I have these following info :

IBagListener interface with two methods which represent a pen which is taken from the bag or added in.

```
abstract void onInPen(Pen pen)
abstract void onOutPen(Pen pen)
```

and i have Bag class with many methods and most important one for you to help me which are :

```
boolean isPenInOrNot(Pen pen)
void    register(IBagListener callback)
```

"register" which "Register an instance of listener to get the callback the in and out event"

My problem is not about creating notifications, it's about setting up and using the listener like how to know which pen became in or out the bag..

Thank you guys !

Comment: Make a class that implements IBagListener, put the code you want to run when a pen is put in or out into the onInPen and onOutPen methods, call register with an instance of your class.  Where in that sequence is the problem or question?

Comment: Your explanations are clear :)

Comment: Yes, a class that implements IBagListener with the code to generate your notifications in the onInPen and onOutPen methods.

Comment: I can call register on an instance of bag class but not on my class that implements IBagListener :x

Comment: Your IBagListner is the *argument* to the register function, not the implementor.    someBag.register(new YourClass());